# Ruby on Rails : Rake db:create -> Could not find gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I begin with ruby on rails and I'm trying to create my first blog. So i ran:

```
rails new blog -database=mysql
```

There was an error:

```
Gem::InstallError: The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.
```

But since i saw a json directory in my blog's directory i didn't care.
So i run the command to create the database:

```
rake db:create --trace
```

And i had another error:

```
Could not find gem 'rails (= 3.1.3) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Does anybody knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Also may need to run

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

Comment: it didn't work
Could not find gem 'rails (= 3.1.3) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Answer (score 0):

you can try "gem list | grep json" to check if json is already install.
Then, you can add following line in Gemfile (in your site's directory):

`gem 'json'`

and then

`bundle install json` or `bundle update json`

Good luck,

Comment: it found json but i've still the same error Could not find gem 'rails (= 3.1.3) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.